# Strong and weak equivalence of $C^*$-extensions by compacts

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, k-theory

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. An *extension of $A$ by the compact operators $K$* is an embedding $\epsilon$ of $A$ into the Calkin algebra $B(H)/K$.

Two embeddings $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are *weakly equivalent* if  $\;u \epsilon_1 (\cdot)u^* = \epsilon_2(\cdot)$ for some unitary $u \in B(H)/K$ and *strongly equivalent* if $u$ has a unitary lift to $B(H)$.

**Question** Apparently weak equivalence classes are strictly larger in general.

- Is there an obvious $K$-theoretic reason for this? In particular, does the unitary group of the Calkin algebra has something to do with this?
- Strong and weak equivalence are the same for abelian $A$. What makes abelian algebras special here?